# Arc lines between 2 objects on a sphere Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I need a little help with maths for drawing lines between 2 points on a sphere. I have a 3d globe and some markers on it. I need to draw curved line from point 1 to point 2. I managed to draw lines from point to point with LineRenderer, but they are drawn with the wrong angle and I can't figure out, how to implement lines that go at the right angle. The code by far:

```
 public static void DrawLine(Transform From, Transform To){
    float count = 12f;
    LineRenderer linerenderer;
    GameObject line = new GameObject("Line");
    linerenderer = line.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
  
    var points = new List<Vector3>();
    Vector3 center = new Vector3(
        (From.transform.position.x + To.transform.position.x) / 2f,
        (From.transform.position.y + To.transform.position.y) ,
        (From.transform.position.z + To.transform.position.z) / 2f
    );

    for (float ratio = 0; ratio <= 1; ratio += 1 / count)
    {
        var tangent1 = Vector3.Lerp(From.position, center, ratio);
        var tangent2 = Vector3.Lerp(center, To.position, ratio);
        var curve = Vector3.Lerp(tangent1, tangent2, ratio);

        points.Add(curve);
    }

    linerenderer.positionCount = points.Count;
    linerenderer.SetPositions(points.ToArray());
}
```

So what I have now is creepy lines rising above along y axis:
[image: screenshot]

What should I take into account to let lines go along the sphere?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to find the normal vector of your two points with a cross product (if your sphere is centered at the origin) and then normalize it to use it as a rotation axis for a rotation using quaternions. To make the interpolations, you can simply rotate the first point around this vector with an angle of k * a where k is a parameter from 0 to 1 and a is the angle between your first two vectors which you can find with the acos() of the dot product of your two normalized points

EDIT : I thought about a much easier solution (again, if the sphere is centered) : you can do a lerp between your two vectors and then normalize the result and multiply it by the radius of the sphere. However, the spacings between the resulting points wont be constant, especially if they are far from each other.

EDIT 2 : you can fix the problem of the second solution by using a function instead of a linear parameter for the lerp : `f(t) = sin(t*a)/sin((PI+a*(1-2*t))/2)/dist(point1, point2)` where a is the angle between the two points.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My sphere is not at the origin, but I'll try to adjust everything so I could try your suggestion. I'll write back if I manage to solve the problem.